# Trying to create a bootable cd from a mac to boot from my windows pc

Tags: installation, boot, windows, mac

I'm trying to create a bootable cd from a mac (running computer) to use to boot and install ubuntu to my pc (not running computer).  Any 'how-tos' or tutorials that can help me?

Answer (score 2):

There's a guide on how to do this on [the Ubuntu homepage](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx):

1. Launch **'Disk Utility'** (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility).
2. Insert your blank DVD.
3. Drag and drop your .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now
   both the blank disc and the .iso should be listed.
4. Select the .iso file, and click on the **'Burn'** button in the toolbar.
5. Ensure that the **'Verify burned data'** checkbox is ticked (you may
   need to click on the disclosure triangle to see the checkbox).
6. Click **'Burn'**. The data will be burned and verified.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent tutorials on [The official Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)